# chpst execution as another user fails cryptically

Tags: linux

Trying to run `chpst` to execute a program as another user, on Ubuntu, gives me the following error:

```
$ chpst -u www-data sh -c whoami
chpst: fatal: unable to setgroups: permission denied
```

The user trying to execute that command is on the `sudoers` file and has privileges to execute any command (`%sudo ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL`).

Also, `www-data` exists as a user and group in both `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group`.

Is anyone able to help out and clarify a) what is chpst complaining about, and b) how to fix this so that the result of the `whoami` execution above yields `www-data`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%sudo ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL` means that every user that belongs to the sudo system group can execute root commands without a password.

But : you still have to use "sudo" in front of the command you want to launch. Plus you should check that the user trying to execute the command belongs to sudo group.
The id command can help you.

> sample@test:~$id uid=1202(sample) gid=1202(sample)
>   groups=1202(sample),4(adm),**27(sudo)**,102(systemd-journal)

If the user does not belong to sudo group, execute
`usermod -a -G sudo your_user` to add the user into the sudo group.

So, when you confirmed that your user belongs to the sudo just run the command like this :
`sudo chpst -u www-data sh -c whoami`

Comment: Brilliant, thanks very much @Rawkins, I completely forgot to use sudo. *facepalm*